# Multiple tables joined to a table via single column

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create query, on below scenario.

[image]

with my skills I am able to join Table A,A1,B and A,A1,C and A,A1,D individually and union them.

Is there any better way to achieve same. I am using Oracle as Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what they mean and if you need to know the columns the values are from.

This would get all the columns and you would have `NULL` values from the non-matching B, C, D tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a1
       INNER JOIN a ON a1.aid = a.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.extid = b.extid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON a.extid = c.extid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN d ON a.extid = d.extid
```

Or, this would get only the relevant values and give you the type they belong to in fewer columns:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   a1
       INNER JOIN a ON a1.aid = a.id
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT extid, 'B' AS type, pqr_col AS col1, qrs_col AS col2 FROM b
         UNION ALL
         SELECT extid, 'C', abc_col, bcd_col FROM c
         UNION ALL
         SELECT extid, 'D', xyz_col, yza_col FROM d
       ) bcd
       ON a.extid = bcd.extid
```

Answer (score 1):

Union was my first thought when I read your question. Though, for simplicity, you could first create a view and then join it to other table(s):

```
create view v_ext as
  select b.extid, b.pqr_col, b.qrs_col from b
  union all
  select c.extid, c.abc_col, c.bcd_col from c
  union all
  select d.extid, d.xyz_col, d.yza_col from d;
  
select *
from a join a1 on a.id = a1.aid
       join v_ext v on v.extid = a.extid;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the query with 'with' clause. Something like below, I havent tested it though

```
with union_output as
  ( select b.extid, b.pqr_col, b.qrs_col from b
    union
    select c.extid, c.abc_col, c.bcd_col from c
    union
    select d.extid, d.xyz_col, d.yza_col from d) 
select *
from a join a1 on a.id = a1.aid
       join union_output uo on uo.extid = a.extid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *from tableA A
Inner join tableA1 A1 on A1.A1ID=A.AID 
Inner join tableB b on b.ExtID=A.ExtID
Inner join tableC c on c.ExtID=A.ExtID
Inner join tableD d on d.ExtID=A.ExtID
```